# iOS CoreBluetooth unable to discover Peripherals

Tags: core-bluetooth

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    dispatch_queue_t queue = dispatch_queue_create("112233", 0);
    _centralManager = [[CBCentralManager alloc] initWithDelegate:self queue:queue options:nil];
}
- (void)centralManagerDidUpdateState:(CBCentralManager *)central
{
    switch (central.state)
    {
        case CBCentralManagerStatePoweredOn:
        {
            [_centralManager scanForPeripheralsWithServices:nil options:nil];
        }
            break;

        default:
            break;
    }
}
- (void)centralManager:(CBCentralManager *)central didDiscoverPeripheral:(CBPeripheral *)peripheral advertisementData:(NSDictionary *)advertisementData RSSI:(NSNumber *)RSSI
{
    NSLog(@"%@",RSSI);
}
```

This is my code.
I tried many times,but it can not discover any bluetooth device.

Hope some can help me.

Comment: What device are you running on?  Have you tried the LightBlue app from the app store to confirm that there are visible BLE peripherals?

Comment: I run on iPhone5s iOS 7.1.1.I tried LightBlue app, it can't discover

Comment: What bluetooth device are you searching for?  It has to be BLE - you won't discover legacy peripherals such as headsets

Comment: I use JBL pulse for peripheral, JBL is BLE

Comment: Have you tried discovering any other BLE device?  It may be that the Pulse is using client/server role switching to discover the app on the phone http://blog.punchthrough.com/post/63658238857/the-apple-notification-center-service-or-wtf-is

Comment: I only have JBL, so I have not tried to discover other BLE device,thank you very much

Comment: Light blue is a pretty solid app so I suspect it is something about the Pulse

Comment: You are right, the problem is JBL pulse. I use lightblue app virtual peripheral on another iPhone 5s then I can discover peripheral,thank you very much.

Comment: What role(as you say) does CoreBluetooth support? Thank you.

Comment: Both peripheral and central role. I suspect that the pulse app either operates as a peripheral, in which case you would see it in light blue on your other phone or it is using service solicitation as a central in which case you will need to know the pulse service uuid and that may be tricky

Comment: JBL Pusle ? It's an audio peripheral? BLE is not designed/suited to transmit audio. Some devices have to be triggered manually (press button) to advertise in BLE for example, did you check that?

Comment: Could you add a log statement to the didUpdateState callback? Maybe you accidentially declined the Bluetooth permission at the first start of the app.